# How to update url with hyperdom-router

Tags: javascript, plastiq

Im trying to update browser url with [Hyperdom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hyperdom) and Hyperdom/Router.

I followed the [documentations](https://github.com/featurist/hyperdom) and  i am seeing no errors , the model property updates but the url does not. My code looks something like this

```
var h = require('hyperdom').html
var router = require('hyperdom/router')

function render (model) {
  var route = router.route('/' + model.type + '/'+ model.currentBrand +'/:screen')

  return h('div.main',
    route({
      bindings:{
        screen: [model,'screen']
      },
      render: function() {
        return renderMain(model)
      }
    })
  )
}
```

Any help will be appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things have changed since Hyperdom was Plastiq, so with hyperdom router we define an object with a `routes()` method, so your example would look a bit more like this:

```js
var h = require('hyperdom').html
var router = require('hyperdom/router')

// this is your route definition
var route = router.route('/:type/:brand/:screen')

// this is your model
var app = {
  // the routes method returns an array
  // of routes with bindings and render methods
  routes: function () {
    return [
      route({
        bindings: {
          type: [this, 'type']
          brand: [this, 'currentBrand']
          screen: [this, 'screen']
        },
        render: function() {
          return this.renderMain()
        }
      })
    ]
  }

  renderMain: function () {
    ...
  }

  // this is called for all routes
  // passing the route content as first argument
  renderLayout: function (content) {
    return h('div.main', content)
  }
}

// mount it
hyperdom.append(document.body, app)
```